# Log4j not working with Weblogic 12c - log file blank

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, cas

I am trying to get CAS 4.0.0 logging correctly with Weblogic 12c on Ubuntu 14.0.4.1.  I have followed every tutorial I can find with no luck.  I have added this line to my startWeblogic.sh:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dlaunch.main.class=${SERVER_CLASS} -Dlaunch.class.path="${CLASSPATH}" -Dlaunch.complete=weblogic.store.internal.LockManagerImpl -Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true -cp ${WL_HOME}/server/lib/pcl2.jar"
```

And I know that worked, because I had my log4j.xml in the wrong spot and it threw and error. I have since fixed that.

I am sure it is reading the log4j.xml because when I start up, I get a log file, but it has 0 size to it.

Here is my log4j.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="cas" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="/opt/cas.log" />
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="512KB" />
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework">
<level value="WARN" />
<appender-ref ref="cas" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.webflow">
<level value="WARN" />
<appender-ref ref="cas" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.jasig" additivity="true">
<level value="DEBUG" />
<appender-ref ref="cas" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.jasig.cas.web.flow" additivity="true">
<level value="WARN" />
<appender-ref ref="cas" />
</logger>

<root>
<level value="DEBUG" />
 <!--   <appender-ref ref="console"/> -->
    <appender-ref ref="cas"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The weird thing is, that even with the console appender commented out, I still get stuff on the console.

Why is nothing going to my log file?

Comment: Go to your server in the weblogic admin console and check the logging tab. Make sure all the settings look correct there as well (e.g. debug level, log4j vs jdk logging, etc.)

Comment: It looks good. Except the log4j vs JDK.  NOWHERE do I see an option for that.  I read all the tutorials, and it should be Logging->General->Advaced But I see nothing there for log4j vs JDK.  But I did add the Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true and set everything to debug mode. I even see in the logs that that loggers are being picked up, but still absolutely nothing in the logs.

Comment: Interesting - there should be a "Logging Implementation" drop down in the advanced section. You can also check "Redirect stdout" and "Redirect stderr" in the advanced section to see if that at least creates the log with the standard terminal output in it

Comment: @mmaceachran, have you solved that issue ?

Comment: No.  I switched to slf4j,  and used regular JDK logging as the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on debug mode: `debug="false"` -> `debug="true"` to see what's wrong there.